# Electric field of uniformly moving charge ; misprint in Feynman textbook? (28.3)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, textbook-erratum

I doubt about formula (28.3) from [this](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_28.html) Feynman's lecture.

$$\textbf{E} = - \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 } \Big{[} \ \frac{e_{r'}}{r'^2}+ \frac{r'}{c} \frac{d}{dt} \Big( \frac{e_{r'}}{r'^2} \Big) + \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{d^2}{dt^2} e_{r'} \ \Big{]}.\tag{28.3} $$

Consider a charge moving along axis $OX$ with constant speed $v$. Let us consider field at a point on the $OX$. Then formula simplified as follows

$$\textbf{E} = - \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 } \Big{[} \ \frac{1}{r'^2}+ \frac{r'}{c} \frac{d}{dt} \Big( \frac{1}{r'^2} \Big) \ \Big{]} e_{r'} = - \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r'^2} \Big{[} \ 1 \pm \frac{2v}{c}  \ \Big{]} e_{r'}$$

*The sign depends on position of two points on the line. But this is not the point...*

This formula seems definitely wrong. The correct formula must have factor $1 \pm \frac{v}{c}$. 
On the other hand there is no such corrections in an [errata](http://www.feynmanlectures.info/errata/FLP_Commemorative_Issue_Vol_II_Errata.pdf).

**Questions**

1. Is it my mistake (when I substitute) or mistake in textbook?
2. If it is mistake in textbook, what is correct formula? Where can I find it?

Comment: General tip: The [Phys.SE H&E policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/2451) may apply to a question even if it is not tagged with the H&E tag. It is the content not the tags that matter.

Comment: If it's in Feynman or Landau's book we say misprint, if it's in Peskin we say mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :**

Your mistake is this
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mathrm dr'}{\mathrm dt}=\boldsymbol{\pm}\,\upsilon
\tag{01-wrong}
\end{equation}

The correct one is
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\mathrm dr'}{\mathrm dt}=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\upsilon}{\dfrac{\upsilon}{c}-1} & \text{for charge }q \text{ to the left of the field point } \mathrm P\\
\\
\dfrac{\upsilon}{\dfrac{\upsilon}{c}+1} & \text{for charge }q \text{ to the right of the field point } \mathrm P 
\end{cases}
\tag{02-right}
\end{equation}
where $\:\upsilon(>0)\:$ the speed of the charge towards the positives of the $\:x-$axis (the velocity  being $\:\boldsymbol{\upsilon}=\upsilon\, \mathbf{i}\:$ where $\:\mathbf{i}\:$ the unit vector on the $\:x-$axis).

Note that
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{e}_{r^{'}}=
\begin{cases}
-\mathbf{i} & \text{for charge }q \text{ to the left of the field point } \mathrm P\\
\\
\hphantom{-}\mathbf{i} & \text{for charge }q \text{ to the right of the field point } \mathrm P 
\end{cases}
\tag{03}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
1-\dfrac{2\, \mathrm dr'}{c\,\mathrm dt}=\dfrac{c\pm\upsilon}{c\mp\upsilon}= 
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{c+\upsilon}{c-\upsilon} & \text{for charge }q \text{ to the left of the field point } \mathrm P\\
\\
\dfrac{c-\upsilon}{c+\upsilon}  & \text{for charge }q \text{ to the right of the field point } \mathrm P 
\end{cases}
\tag{04}
\end{equation}

[image]

Video here : [**Electric field of a uniformly moving point charge**](https://vimeo.com/249929049)

Comment: Let $\beta = \frac{v}{c}$. It is nice to note, that $r' = \frac{r}{1 \mp \beta}$. So the answer is $\frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{(1 \mp \beta)^2 (1 \pm \beta)}{(1 \mp \beta)r^2} = \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{1 - \beta^2}{r^2}$. This factor $1 - \beta^2$ can be interpreted as Lorenz contraction.

More pricesly, $F_{\mu \nu}$ tensor is invariant under Lorenz transformation (in this particular case).So $E= \frac{q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{1}{r_0^2}$. Here is the distance in system of the charge (between the charge and the observer at the same moment). Then $r_0 = r \sqrt{1-\beta^2}$

Comment: @quinque : Precisely. You're right.